# how to call a javascript function on page load from every jsp page

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, breadcrumbs

i have a javascript  breadcrumbs() function

and i want that this function should be call on page load of every jsp page ,so my breadcrumb can be set for all jsp.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Any code you have? What's the structure?

Comment: You can call that function as usual on the `onload` event of the `<body>` tag. There is no magical way to do so. What are your functional requirements?

Comment: actually i am not using <body> and <script> tag , i am making all jsp code in different <div class=""> tag and also using EL and JSTL tags so i can't understand where i will write this onload function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<%@include file="script.jsp" %>
```

to embed the script into the page code directly. This would be preferable if the script is small and JSP can even customize it for every page, if required.

Answer (score 0):

you can put on body tag like this

```
<body onload="breadcrumbs()">
```